# How to create a runnable jar that uses files and images as

Tags: java, jar, resources, package

I want to understand the best or the standard technique to write a java project when using internal files. To be precise, I want to develop a project that uses text files and images that are needed when the program runs. My goal is to create a runnable jar from the project in which the user does not need to see all these files. Therefore, I decided to create a package called resources and put it inside the folder that contains the source codes. I.e. it is in the same level as other packages. Now, in my codes when I want to use the images I use the following statement: 
URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/image1.gif");
It is working!
Then, to open a text file for reading/writing, I use the following:
String filename= "/resources/"+file1.txt; 
Now, this is not working and it complains that it cannot find the file. I am not sure how to go about this? 
A google search suggested that I put the resources folder on the project root directory. It is working then but when I created the runnable jar I had to put the resources folder on the same directory as the jar. This means  that the user can have access to all the files in there. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getResource` method for files too.

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/file1.txt");
try {
    File f = new File(fileUrl.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    //dealing with the exception 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your help. It is still not working for me!

Comment: I had the following codes: String file = "resources/file1.txt";
  java.net.URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file);
  File f = null;
  try {
   f = new File(url.toURI());
  } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  String fileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
  System.out.println("File Name: "+fileName); It is working fine in the IDE; I am using Eclipse on Windows, but when I jar it the program does not print the last statement and halts.